# return 1 column from relation in 1 array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

everybody, I need to return just imagePath in images into 1 array not objects 
has many relation
any  ideas

```
    $albums_category = AlbumCategory::with('albums.images')->find($id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
$album = AlbumCategory::with('images')->find($id);

$imagePaths = $album->images->pluck('imagePath');
```

or if you have nested relation then :

```
$album = AlbumCategory::with('albums.images')->find($id);
$imagemapths = [];

$album->albums->each(function($album) use($imagemapths){

    return array_merge($album->images->pluck('imagePath'), $imagemapths);
});
```

However, if you are plucking just one column, its better to just select it and avoid selecting columns from database you do not need. SO you can do :

```
$album = AlbumCategory::with('albums.images:id,imagepath')->find($id);
```

or similar using `:foreign_key,column_to_select` depending on  your table stucture.

Comment: $album = AlbumCategory::with('albums.images:id,imagepath')->find($id);
  i have try it but get empty array of images

Comment: Are you getting it without specifying `:id,imagepath`?